# Get one value before the timerange in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, influxql, influxdb-python, flux-influxdb

I have the below time series data in my measurement:

[image: Time series data]

I'm receiving the below values from the user for the start and end time:

```
Start : '2023-06-12T06:20:00Z'
End :  '2023-06-12T09:00:00Z'
```

On basis of the above parameters, I want this data to be selected:

[image]

Basically, I want one more record other than the ones in the range specified by the user which is just before the start time specified by the user.

Is there a function in InfluxDB that can do this?